# Re-enter EU with renewed US passport

Tags: eu, schengen, passport

After staying in Spain for 87 days I got back to US to renew my passport. Can I re-enter Spain earlier than having to stay outside for 90 days using my new passport?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked at travel.stackxchange (90 days in 180 day period).

Comment: Yes, you could enter for 3 days. There is no **reset** for the 90/180 days rule.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The 90 day rule applies to you *as a person*, rather than *your passport*. If you attempt to enter Spain with your new passport, they will very likely be able to link up your identity with your previous passport and deny you entry.

Comment: Until the Entry/Exit System (EES) is introduced (expected at the end of May 2023), it is actualy **unlikely** to be noticed due to the lack of entry/exit stamps in the new passport.